# How can i show new messages using PHP messaging system?

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and have been reading some books and tutorials, and I have started working on a php messaging site just to learn some techniques. The problem is that i cannot work out how to refresh the list of messages that a user is displayed.

For example, when a user is sent a message they will not receive it until their webpage is refreshed. I realise that i could simply refresh the page on a interval but then if a long message is being written chances are the page will refresh before the message is sent.

As i haven't been able to find a solution i can get my head around online, thought i would ask on here :)
My question to the internet is: Is there a way to refresh one section of the page, or keep drawing data from a database and echo it to the user.

Here is the code for the page which displays the messages to the user.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Conversations - Hepburn's Messager</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>



<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
<?php include 'functions.php'; ?>
<?php include 'title_bar.php'; ?>
<div class='container-fluid'>
        <h3>Conversations - Hepburn's Messager</h3>

  <?php include 'message_title_bar.php' ?>
  <?php
        $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

  ?>
  <div>
  <?php


    if(isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])) {

      $hash = $_GET['hash'];
    $message_query = mysql_query("SELECT from_id, message FROM messages WHERE group_hash='$hash'");

    while($run_message = mysql_fetch_array($message_query)) {

      $from_id = $run_message['from_id'];
      $message = $run_message['message'];

        $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='$from_id'");
        $run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);
      $from_username = $run_user['username'];

    echo "<p><b>$from_username</b><br/>$message</p>";

    setInterval(function(){
    echo "hi!\n";
        }, 1000);
        }
  ?>
        <br/>
        <form method='post'>
                <?php
                if(isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])){
                        $new_message = $_POST['message'];
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages VALUES('', '$hash', '$my_id', '$new_message')");
                        header('location: conversations.php?hash='.$hash);
                }
                ?>
                <h4>Enter Message:</h4>
                <textarea class='form-control' rows='6' cols='50' name='message'></textarea>
                <input class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' type='submit' value='Send Message'/>      <!-- problem -->
        </form>
  <?php
  } else {
        echo "<h4>Select a conversation:<h4>";
        $get_con = mysql_query("SELECT hash, user_one, user_two FROM message_group WHERE user_one='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'");

        while($run_con = mysql_fetch_array($get_con)){

                $hash = $run_con['hash'];
                $user_one = $run_con['user_one'];
                $user_two = $run_con['user_two'];


                if($user_one == $my_id){
                        $select_id = $user_two;
                } else {
                        $select_id = $user_one;
                }

                $user_get = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='$select_id'");
                $run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_get);

                $select_username = $run_user['username'];

                echo "<p><a href='conversations.php?hash=$hash'>$select_username</a></p>";

        }

  }
  ?>   
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: js\jquery and ajax could refresh just a div every minute to check for new messages

Comment: being new: stop with `mysql_*` its being removed may as well learn something with a future

Comment: So if i separate the messages and the send form into different divs, then i can refresh just the single div?

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: If you want a true messaging system look into websockets. http://socketo.me/

Comment: Thanks for all the awesome info guys :)

Comment: PHP can do a lot of things but it's not the best tool for this kind of problem. Try googling java ee sockets.